# How to find a value in List of dictionary of dictionary of List in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am quite new in Python.
I have to find/compare a string value with a list which is present inside a List of dictionary of dictionary of List. I wrote the code below, though it is working fine but can we write in some better way.

```
abc = [{'GetDriverPackInfo_OUTPUT': {'OSList': [u'Linux', u'Windows', u'Xen', u'VMware'], 'ReturnValue': [u'0'], 'Version': [u'15.07.04']}}]

os_name = "Linux"

for k in abc:                   #['GetDriverPackInfo_OUTPUT']['OSList']:
    if os_name in k['GetDriverPackInfo_OUTPUT']['OSList']: #== os_name:
        print ("os_name found")
    else:
        print ("os_name not found")
```

Comment: ensure each outer dict has key `GetDriverPackInfo_OUTPUT` and each inner dict has key `OSList`? otherwise the `if` statement may throw exception

Comment: will abc always have one 'GetDriverPackInfo_OUTPUT'?

Comment: @fahad: Yes `abc` will be always 'GetDriverPackInfo_OUTPUT'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this works for you. It'll work only if abc always has one 'GetDriverPackInfo_OUTPUT' item.

temp = abc[0]['GetDriverPackInfo_OUTPUT']['OSList']

if os_name in temp:

```
  print "found"
```

else:

```
  print "not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: osname in [j for j in [k['GetDriverPackInfo_OUTPUT']['OSList'] for k in abc]][0]
Out[1]: True
```

If it's return True the osname exits else it's not.